# How to make a sequence diagram for this?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

A group diary and time management system is intended to support the timetabling of
meetings and appointments across a group of coworkers. When an appointment is to be
made that involves a number of people, the system finds a common slot in each of their
diaries and arranges the appointment for that time. If no common slots are available, it
interacts with the user to rearrange his or her personal diary to make room for the
appointment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First step is to think about what objects you have in the system. Make a list of candidates.
- Now think about how does this scenario get initiated. Where does the message come from? Draw that incoming message.
- The next step is to think about which object is going to receive that message. Now in order to do the work that object will probably need to talk to other objects. Sketch out the other object with an arrow and a message name.
- Keep thinking about the sequence of messages and the objects to which the messages go - and try sketching them out one at a time.
- Don't expect to get it right first time. Try sketching out several approaches.

Answer (score 1):

A sequence diagram describes interactions between objects that achieve some goal.

So your first step needs to be to identify some objects (and actors). If you start with that step, show us your attempt, then we have something to discuss further.

Comment: I'll guess that the actor is the user of the system who is trying to schedule an appointment.  I'll guess that the objects are the UI and some kind of database.  What do you think?

Comment: This seems to be an exercise in OO design. I think that you are being asked to decompose the business logic of the system. For example there might be a Scheduler object, a UsersDiary object and probably some more objects within the diary.  You're being asked to think about how these objects interact.

Answer (score 1):

"You should identify possible objects in the following systems and develop an object-oriented design for them. You may make any reasonable assumptions about the systems when deriving the design."

From `Chapter 14 Exercise 14.7`

Comment: Wow how did you find that.  Are you taking a class with the same textbook?